# Which parameters we fill in FirestoreListCollectionIdsParams struct (rust library)

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, rust

I am querying the Collection Ids so I am using Firestore library (https://docs.rs/firestore/latest/firestore/index.html) the method on db uses struct `FirestoreListCollectionIdsParams()` as parameter but I need to understand what this fields mean because I get auth error
(for struct https://docs.rs/firestore/latest/firestore/struct.FirestoreListCollectionIdsParams.html)

```
pub struct FirestoreListCollectionIdsParams {
    pub parent: Option<String>,
    pub page_size: usize,
    pub page_token: Option<String>,
}
```

I am using that struct like this

```
  let db = FirestoreDb::with_options_service_account_key_file(
        FirestoreDbOptions::new("projectID".to_string()),
        "key.json".into(),
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();

  let param = FirestoreListCollectionIdsParams {
        parent: Some("Cards".to_owned()),
        page_size: 1,
        page_token: Some("Cards".to_owned()),
    };

let test_struc = db.list_collection_ids(param).await?;

    println!("Read {:?}", test_struc);
```

I need to know what "page_size", "page_token" and "parent" fields are responsible for.

Answer (score 2):

This Rust library is almost certainly just calling out to the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/) and using the [listCollectionIds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds) endpoint.  Using that linked documentation, you can easily see what they are:

> **parent**
>
> string
>
> Required. The parent document. In the format: projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}. For example: projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents/chatrooms/my-chatroom

> **pageSize**
>
> integer
>
> The maximum number of results to return.

> **pageToken**
>
> string
>
> A page token. Must be a value from ListCollectionIdsResponse.

You will likely have to keep following the links in that documentation to get a full view of what everything is.

Comment: `parent: Option<String>` — Required … I know you're likely not responsible for that decision but a required `Option` is a really bad design choice.

Comment: Please feel free to send feedback to whomever authored that SDK.